# How to have a tub faucet, shower head, and rain shower head?

Tags: plumbing, water, shower, bathtub, pex

I am remodeling my bathroom and installing a new bathtub. I would like to have the tub outlet, a shower head outlet, and a ceiling rain outlet. I would like to use the rain shower head and the normal shower head at the same time.

A little background info. I redid all of my water lines in my home. The wall is all torn apart and waiting for me to put in the rough-in valve. I have a 3/4” PEX main line with 1/2” branches for both hot and cold water lines. All the valves I have looked at have fittings for 1/2”, not 3/4” so I am assuming the best way to run the water lines is 1/2” branches from my main trunk. (Please correct me if I am wrong)

I have done some research and come up with a few possibilities:

1. Find a specialty valve that offers the three options, with the diverting integrated, with their specialty trim offerings. ($$$)
2. Run a diverter down line off of a normal tub/shower valve (think Delta or Moen) that controls the shower head and rain head. (I think a little less money than the first option?)
3. Run two separate valves, one for the tub/shower and one for the rain head. I would run separate 1/2” PEX lines off my 3/4” main branch. (Assuming this is the cheapest option, as the tub/shower combo sets aren’t super expensive and just a shower valve should be comparable).

What are your suggestions?

Comment: I think you need option 3 simply based on water volume delivered if you intend to use a rain shower and a normal showerhead **at the same time.** - Then find out if your water heater keeps up with that for long enough to take a shower.

Comment: Don't run two 1/2" lines - run a single 3/4" line. A single 3/4" line has 4 times the carrying capacity of 1/2", i.e. it's more than even two 1/2" lines. You can then split the 3/4 as needed in the bathroom.

Comment: This needs to be two different questions. The size of the line two run should be a different question from what shower faucet/outlet should I buy/build.

Answer (score 0):

When I did mine the valve came with three outlets, one for the rain shower, one for the hand strayer and the third we connected to the regular shower head. It was part of a Kit I purchased at the local box store. It was a name brand (M) in brushed stainless finish. It was not that expensive. You can check before you purchase it. It was labeled 2-way and only showed two connections but it had three, both of them. You could also add a diverter valve to one of the outlets on your planned valve and switch between shower heads, tub or whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of installing a pressure-balance valve, where the same valve controls on/off and temperature, install a thermostatic valve, which only controls temperature, and then install 3 volume control valves for your various fixtures.

It's not cheap, but you'll have much better results.